# System freezes after VGA output goes crazy

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, vga

I am running a dual monitor setup with one running off VGA and the other off DVI on a Asus H97 motherboard. Integrated graphics from an i7-4790. And Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS updated to the latest avaliable kernel i.e 3.13.0-43) as the sole operating system.

Lately I've been having this weird crash where both my screens will go blank momentarily and then come back. Only, my VGA display would be flashing colors and the system would be non-resposive. Not even the hardware reset works(though holding down the power button for 10 secs shuts it off). This kind of crash has happened once while running a single monitor as well and once while in the BIOS. My BIOS is running "optimized defaults" with only the fan speeds being tuned. Sometimes I would get the blank screen+weird flashing colors without the system freezing up, in which case unplugging and plugging the VGA monitor back in fixes it.

What do I do? Please help.

My system:

CPU = Intel Core i7-4790 3.6GHz Quad-Core Processor

Motherboard = Asus H97M-E Micro ATX LGA1150 Motherboard

Memory = Corsair Vengeance 4GB (1 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory x2

Storage = Samsung 850 EVO-Series 120GB 2.5" Solid State Drive

Power Supply = Corsair RM 450W 80+ Gold Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply

Monitor = BenQ GW2255 60Hz 21.5" Monitor and Samsung S20C200B 20.0" Monitor

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer... although why isn't entirely clear... I suppose I need a tiny bit more information.  So, can you tell us how old this system is, or rather, how many years are on the display card.  I'm guessing 3-4, in which case, I believe I know the answer and will get back to you when you confirm my age estimate.

Comment: The whole system is really new. Barely 6 months old. And I'm using the integrated intel-HD graphics, not any video card.

Comment: Well then, unless you have parrots or something, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the nvidia driver and then try to install it again,

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using in-built intel HD graphics.